# What's the difference between ，and 、

Tags: difference, punctuation

What's the difference between ，and 、 as they appear in some texts, like in [this passage](http://ctext.org/zhuangzi/man-in-the-world-associated-with) of the Zhuang Zi (end of the second part):

是萬物之化也，禹、舜之所紐也，伏戲、几蘧之所行終，而況散焉者乎！

Is it like comma and semicolon? Or one is used for enumerations, or what?

Comment: FYI. There are punctuations in the old Chinese text but it is not written or printed often. What you found in old book might be "是萬物之化也禹舜之所紐也伏戲几蘧之所行終而況散焉者乎".  In those old days, it is quite basic to learn breaking sentence in phrase by own effort. They marks it lower right conner with "。" for ending of sentence and "、" for pausing.   The use of "，" comes very lately by Western influence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Q： The difference between ，and 、

，(逗号， Dou4 Hao4) is similar to what it is for in English.

、(顿号，Dun4 Hao4) is to give a list of same type of things.

For example: 
我喜欢吃苹果、香蕉、橘子、等等。

If in English, it would be also a comma.

Answer (score 1):

`、` is used for enumerations. `，` is the counterpart of `,`

Comment: Thanks! But how to type it in a pinyin-enabled keyboard? I have just copied it here...

Comment: “\” in Chinese Mode.
、、、
See, I just tested it.