# 这段课文写对了没有? 请你们检查一下。谢谢

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, usage, sentence-structure, writing-critique

Please help me to check if my text for the video is correct. 大家好! 我是_, 我来自俄罗斯, 今年20岁。 目前还是一个_大学外国语学院的学生。 我是一个渴望知识的人, 学得很认真和努力。 我家不太富裕, 我从中学工作和帮助解决金钱问题。 从那时起，我试图了解金融和经济学是如何运作的, 觉得很有意思。 在我上学期间, 也对数学和分析非常感兴趣, 所以想在_大学学习金融。 日常的生活我喜欢看小说, 学外语和聊天跟外国人。 感谢您的收看。

Comment: Just for curiosity sake, may I ask how long have you been studying the language?

Answer (score 2):

大家好! 我是____, 我来自俄罗斯, 今年20岁。 目前还是[一个]__*大学外国语学院的学生。 我是一个渴望知识的人, 学得很认真和努力。 我家不太富裕, 我从中学**開始**工作[和]帮助解决金钱问题。 从那时起，我试图**着**了解金融和经济[学]是如何运作的, **對那**觉得很有[意思]**興趣**。 **而**在我上学期间, [也]对数学和分析**也**非常感兴趣, 所以想在[*]大学]**同時**学习金融**和外国语**。 日常的生活我喜欢看小说, 学外语和[聊天}跟外国人**聊天**。 感谢您的收看。

The writing is very fluent, congratulation! I've made minor changes to make it a little smoother.

**[  ]** - delete the word(s).

Comment: All  those who answered to date probably felt that  感谢您的收看 requires no "improvement" So, my question is, is "收看" all that appropriate given OP's intention and request?

Comment: Yes. Because he is making a video resume.

Answer (score 2):

大家好! 我叫_, 来自俄罗斯, 今年20岁。 目前还是_大学外国语学院的学生。我是一个渴望知识的人, 学得很认真也很努力。我家不太富裕, 所以我从中学就开始打工，帮助家里解决经济困难。从那时起，我开始试图了解金融和经济是如何运作的, 并对它们产生了兴趣。在我上学期间, 也对数学和分析非常感兴趣, 所以想在_大学学习金融。 在日常生活中，我喜欢看小说、学外语和跟外国人聊天。我的自我介绍就到这里，感谢您的收看。

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it (I'm late-HSK6 student).  To begin, note that there is no space after a full stop in Chinese, and the Chinese comma is written ， and not ,.

> 大家好！我是_，我来自俄罗斯，今年20岁。

That's fine.

> 目前**我**还是一个_大学外国语学院的学生。

This sentence originally lacked a subject (although maybe you can infer the subject).  I'd also be tempted to add a 属于, but it looks like it's okay without it.

> Original: 我是一个渴望知识的人，学得很认真和努力。
> Mine: 我是一个渴望知识的人，学得**又认真又努力**。

Perhaps this is one of those rare cases where [和 can be used to connect adjectives](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22and%22_with_%22he%22_(advanced)#Linking_Adjectives_with_.E5.92.8C), but ordinarily [和 connects nouns](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22and%22_with_%22he%22) (and sometimes verbs with common subjects and objects), while [又……又…… is used to connect adjectives](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22both_A_and_B%22_with_%22you%22).

> Original: 我家不太富裕, 我从中学工作和帮助解决金钱问题。
> Mine: 我家不太富裕，**所以为了**帮助**减轻家庭的经济负担**，我从中学**开始**工作。

This sentence gives (a) a reason why you need to help (so it's natural to use 所以), and (b) what you goal of helping is (so it's natural to use 为了).  I use a common way of saying "help out financially" in Chinese, 减轻家庭的经济负担 = "lighten the family's economic burden".  I don't have a good explanation here, but 从中学 by itself feels incomplete.

> Original: 从那时起，我试图了解金融和经济学是如何运作的, 觉得很有意思。
> Mine: 从那时起，我**尽量**了解金融和经济学是如何运作的, 觉得**这些话题**很有意思。

Here 试图 needs to be modified to indicate an ongoing process; there are multiple ways of achieving this.  The issue with 我……觉得很有意思 is that it doesn't specify what is interesting (such as in 我觉得**它**很有意思).

> Original: 在我上学期间, 也对数学和分析非常感兴趣, 所以想在_大学学习金融。
> Mine: **我**在上学时, 也对数学和分析非常感兴趣, 所以想在_大学学习金融。

The problem here is there is no subject (the 我 comes after the 在, so it only plays a role in specifying the timeframe); it doesn't say who is interested in math and analysis.

> Original: 日常的生活我喜欢看小说, 学外语和聊天跟外国人。 感谢您的收看。
> Mine: **在**日常的生活**中**，我喜欢看小说、学外语和**跟外国人聊天**。

Using 在日常的生活中 without the 在……中 might be acceptable, but it's not familiar to me.  Note the use of the [、 comma instead of the ， comma](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/12299/8099).  Most important here is that 聊天 is a [separable verb](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Separable_verb) so we need to use separable verb grammar.  In this case, we need to use the structure 跟……聊天.

> 感谢您的收看。

That's fine.

Comment: While 属于 is grammatical to add, it makes the sentence very unnatural. 试图 is better than 尽量. It is a still-going process from then. 了解 cannot be the predicate here; I don't know the term, but it's not "verbal" enough. 尽量去了解 solves the problem.

Comment: Another thing feels awkward is 看小说、学外语和跟外国人聊天. Change 和 to 以及 is much better. This is phonetic.

Comment: Chinese language is more flexible than English and other western languages. But there is still some work to be done for better reading. 看小说、学外语还有跟外国人聊天 is a better choice, 谢谢您的观看 is more natural than 感谢您的收看. 收看is a formal word often used to highlight the show to be watched, like an important event, and sounds a little awkward when what you like others to watch is a short video of your self-introduction.

Answer (score 1):

大家好!我是_,我来自俄罗斯,今年20岁。目前是_大学外国语学院的学生。我是一个渴望知识的人, 学得很认真努力。我家不太富裕,我从中学开始工作以解决金钱问题。从那时起，我试图了解金融和经济学是如何运作的, 觉得很有意思。在我上学期间, 也对数学和分析非常感兴趣, 所以想在_大学学习金融。 在日常生活中我喜欢看小说, 学外语和跟外国人聊天。感谢您的观看。

No space is needed. 空格是不需要的。

Use less “and”. "and" doesn't have many meaning in chinese. 在中文中，“和”有时可以被省略，或使用更具体的关联词，“和”没有那么多的隐藏含义。